# How to scroll frame widget in perl using Tk module

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

How to attach scrollbar widget to frame? I tryied to do this like with other widgets like text or entry but I've got error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Scrolled constructor part of the tk.

Read up on it here

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/pod/Scrolled.pod

Comment: Thank you, I read about it and it is useful but I can't find Tk::Scrolled in cpan for my perl. Is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Tk::Pane](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/Tk/Pane.pm).

> Tk::Pane provides a scrollable frame widget. Once created it can be treated as a frame, except it is scrollable.

Note: [Tk::Scrolled](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tk%3a%3aScrolled) is part of the standard Tk distribution. Did you try to use it like this (untested)?

```
my $scrolled_frame = $parent->Scrolled('Frame', -scrollbars => 'se')->pack;
```